# Variable, Class, function etc. inspector for Atom

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor, atom-editor

For visual studio code, there exists some addon/plugin which shows you the origin for example of an included class, the return value of a function etc.. 
I find it very handy, but I want this functionality in atom since I prefer atom.

How does one call this kind of plugin/addon, so I can look for it on google?
And ideally, what addon/plugin supports this feature best.

Comment: Intellisense..?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, the functionality name is `IntelliSense`. 
About IntelliSense used in `VS code`, you can read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/using-intellisense?view=vs-2019). 
Actually you must do your research depending on programming language you use. I.e. if you're using `js` you must search `javascript Intellisense atom` and find it in first [link](https://atom.io/packages/atom-ternjs)